# java logback custom logger name

Tags: java, logging, logback

I want to create the following logback configuration:

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="INCOMING_REQUESTS_LOG" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>./logs/incoming_requests.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <!-- encoders are assigned the type
             ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date %-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} | %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>



    <logger name="mysuperduperlogger" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="INCOMING_REQUESTS_LOG"/>
    </logger>
</configuration>
```

Can I use

```
logger name="mysuperduperlogger"
```

as logback logger name and how to access  it in my code? In documentation I could found only loggers like "com.mypackage.myclass.aa1"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you create a instance of `Logger` you can do so in two ways.

1. By Class
2. By String

If you use by Class like

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Test.class);
```

and the class name including the package is `org.example.Test` then to configure logs for this logger the name can be `org.example.Test`

If you use by String like

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger("TestLogger");
```

then to configure logs for this logger the name can be `TestLogger`

So if you want to use `mysuperduperlogger` as logger name you have to create a `Logger` instance as follows.

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger("mysuperduperlogger");
```

Comment: Issue with above solution is not printing the package name in the log file instead it is printing loggername

Comment: @PrasadReddy Yes, if you use `LoggerFactory.getLogger(String loggerName);` it will print the string passed for `loggerName` that the default behaviour.

Comment: I need package name to be printed.How to do that.Because I wont be able to know with string name from which package is printed. This is not the same case when i was using log4j.properties

Comment: @PrasadReddy if you want to print just use `LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClassName.class);` in this case you cannot use a named logger in the configurations.

Answer (score 3):

Just to extend a bit on @karthikeyan-vaithilingam's answer and the subsequent question of @user1001, you can have a custom logger name AND the package name by simply concatenating them (though it gets into a quite lengthy construction):

```
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass().getPackageName() + ".mysuperduperlogger");
```

My recommendation: define all the logger names into a class with string constants, place it in a shared common module, and reference it from there.

Why?: The logger names are basically an API that you expose towards the admins of your application, you want to define this API carefully and make sure that any small-to-medium refactoring of the code (say, renaming a class or moving a class to a subpackage) does not break the existing logging configuration from where your app is deployed.